# google iframe 'causeing extra padding on the bottom

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have the below HTML code:

```
<div class="google-maps">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d109782.8671228349!2d76.62734023564995!3d30.69830520749905!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x390fee906da6f81f%3A0x512998f16ce508d8!2sSahibzada+Ajit+Singh+Nagar%2C+Punjab!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1449838222081"
  width="100%" height="150" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Now i have the following CSS:

```
body {
  color: #fff;
}

.google-maps {
  margin: 1em 0;
  background: #000;
  padding: .5em;
}
```

I have gone through the HTML and the CSS thoroughly , but i can't figure out whats 'causing the extra padding at the bottom in spite of the even padding i have given I.E.

```
padding: .5em;
```

can somebody explain why am i getting this uneven padding ?

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/s3mzdh4d/)**

Answer (score 9):

`iframe` has `display:inline;` by default, it acts like a letter. For example, when you have `a` letter there is some spaces below the letter. However, you can use the below solutions:

1- `vertical-align:bottom;` [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/s3mzdh4d/5/)

2- `display:block;` [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/s3mzdh4d/6/)

or ..

Here is the image which is shown the extra space(`2px`).

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/o257a7Lj/)

[image]

Comment: plus one , if you have anything to suppose your claim , i'll accept ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't technically with the padding; there is a small space after the iframe that is picking up the `background: #000;` style.

There is a similar issue located here: [Unwanted Padding in IE Image Rendering in div Tag](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2008/Jun/05/Unwanted-Padding-in-IE-Image-Rendering-in-div-Tag)

I modified your fiddle and added a `display: block;` to the iframe, ran the fiddle, and all was well with the output (i.e. no more uneven padding). [Here is that fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3mzdh4d/).